# Using C++ classes in Arduino

Tags: c++, class, arduino

I need to use classes in Arduino to be able to multitask. I've found a class example in [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/a-classy-solution) but I wanted to keep my main code clean, so I've decided to put the class in **.h** and **.cpp** files. After a bit of googling this is what I've came up with: 
**Work.h** file:

```
/*
 * Work.h
 *
 *  Created on: 2016-05-09
 *      Author: Secret
 */

#ifndef WORK_H_
#define WORK_H_
int ledPin;      // the number of the LED pin
unsigned long OnTime;     // milliseconds of on-time
unsigned long OffTime;    // milliseconds of off-time

int ledState;                   // ledState used to set the LED
unsigned long previousMillis;   // will store last time LED was updated
class Work {

public:
    Work(int pin, long on, long off);
    void Update();
};

#endif /* WORK_H_ */
```

**Work.cpp** file:

```
/*
 * Work.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 2016-05-09
 *      Author: Secret
 */

#include "Work.h"
#include <Arduino.h>

Work::Work(int pin, long on, long off) {

    ledPin = pin;
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

    OnTime = on;
    OffTime = off;

    ledState = LOW;
    previousMillis = 0;

}
void Update() {
    // check to see if it's time to change the state of the LED
    unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

    if ((ledState == HIGH) && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OnTime)) {
        ledState = LOW;  // Turn it off
        previousMillis = currentMillis;  // Remember the time
        digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);  // Update the actual LED
    } else if ((ledState == LOW)
            && (currentMillis - previousMillis >= OffTime)) {
        ledState = HIGH;  // turn it on
        previousMillis = currentMillis;   // Remember the time
        digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);   // Update the actual LED
    }
}
```

When I tried compiling, I got errors that in Work.cpp, method Update() I've got multiple definitions of **OnTime**, **OffTime**, **ledState**, **previousMillis**.
What am I doing wrong here and how to solve this?

Comment: Why are you *defining* those variables in the header file globally? Why aren't those variables *member* variables in the class?

Comment: A) you don't need classes to multitask, B) your problem is not related to classes.

Comment: A) as far as I've read, I do need classes to multitask properly. Check the article I've linked. B) How is it not related to classes if I'm writing a C++ class for Arduino?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error means you have those variables appearing in multiple translation units. By default, non-`const` global variables have external linkage.

To make it internal, you can qualify it with `static`. Or you can simply move the definitions to your translation unit (.cpp file)

---

Qualify with `static` in Work.h

```
static int ledPin;      // the number of the LED pin
static unsigned long OnTime;     // milliseconds of on-time
static unsigned long OffTime;    // milliseconds of off-time

static int ledState;                   // ledState used to set the LED
static unsigned long previousMillis;   // will store last time LED was updated
class Work {

public:
    Work(int pin, long on, long off);
    void Update();
};
```

Preferably, move them to your .cpp files since you aren't using them in your Work.h file.

**EDIT**

The error resulted from your `Update()` function in the .cpp file.

```
void Update() { ....
```

^^ that defined a new function, and is using those global variables... I believe you wanted to do

```
void Work::Update() {....
```

Comment: Thank you for such fast response. I've moved the variables to Work.cpp file. Also made changes to the definition of Update() method as @Saad_Qureshi suggested. Everything works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Since the method Update() is a part of class Work, it should be defined within the scope of Work class like this:

```
void Work :: Update () {....
```